# Multidimensional array sort and unique by key- PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
$mp = array(
array('url'=>'www.abc.com','time'=>'1433551154','referral_url'=>'www.pqr.com'),
array('url'=>'www.xyz.com','time'=>'1433551150','referral_url'=>'www.stu.com'),
array('url'=>'www.lmn.com','time'=>'1433551190','referral_url'=>'www.jhi.com'),
array('url'=>'www.rst.com','time'=>'1433551170','referral_url'=>'www.pqr.com')
);
```

The above is the input array, I need output with sort by time and unique by referral_url.

Resultant will be-

```
$mp = array(
array('url'=>'www.lmn.com','time'=>'1433551190','referral_url'=>'www.jhi.com'),
array('url'=>'www.rst.com','time'=>'1433551170','referral_url'=>'www.pqr.com'),
array('url'=>'www.lmn.com','time'=>'1433551150','referral_url'=>'www.stu.com'),
);
```

Remember first sort by time then remove the duplicate by referral_url.

My Code, what i tried-

```
public function unique_sort($arrs, $id) {
    $unique_arr = array();
    foreach ($arrs AS $arr) {

        if (!in_array($arr[$id], $unique_arr)) {
            $unique_arr[] = $arr[$id];
        }
    }
    sort($unique_arr);
    return $unique_arr;
} 
foreach($mp as $key => $row){
        $referral_url[$key]  = $row['referral_url'];
        $time[$key] = $row['time'];
        $url[$key] = $row['url'];
    }
array_multisort($time, SORT_DESC, $mp);
$sort_arr = $this->unique_sort($mp, 'referral_url');
print_R($uniqueArray);exit;
```

But it only result me referral_url-

```
Array(
[0] => www.jhi.com
[1] => www.pqr.com
[2] => www.stu.com
)
```

i need all as above defined output.

Please suggest the way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no i dont think so. also I tried that code but it not works for me. in this i want unique on referral_url also. I am able to find the sort but not getting how to get full array not only referral_url with their other key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$mp = array(
array('url'=>'www.abc.com','time'=>'1433551154','referral_url'=>'www.pqr.com'),
array('url'=>'www.xyz.com','time'=>'1433551150','referral_url'=>'www.stu.com'),
array('url'=>'www.lmn.com','time'=>'1433551190','referral_url'=>'www.jhi.com'),
array('url'=>'www.rst.com','time'=>'1433551170','referral_url'=>'www.pqr.com')
);
uasort($mp,function($a,$b){
    return $b['time'] - $a['time'];
});

foreach($mp as $value){
    $hash = $value['referral_url'];
    if(!isset($result[$hash])){
       $result[$hash] = $value;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

**Explanation :**

Used `uasort` to sort an array based on time which will result into following array

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.lmn.com
            [time] => 1433551190
            [referral_url] => www.jhi.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.rst.com
            [time] => 1433551170
            [referral_url] => www.pqr.com
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.abc.com
            [time] => 1433551154
            [referral_url] => www.pqr.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.xyz.com
            [time] => 1433551150
            [referral_url] => www.stu.com
        )

)
```

And within `foreach` loop making an array of values having *unique* `referral_url` which will result into following array

```
Array
(
    [www.jhi.com] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.lmn.com
            [time] => 1433551190
            [referral_url] => www.jhi.com
        )

    [www.pqr.com] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.rst.com
            [time] => 1433551170
            [referral_url] => www.pqr.com
        )

    [www.stu.com] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.xyz.com
            [time] => 1433551150
            [referral_url] => www.stu.com
        )

)
```

And finally used `array_values` for values only having integer keys

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/398460)

Comment: It take the last value from sorted array. OP want the 1st. Add test if exist

Comment: @splash58 I think the result is as OP shown within its resultant array _Resultant will be-_

Comment: i am not agree with you

Comment: Have a look at this statement _The above is the input array, I need output with sort by time and unique by referral_url._ @splash58 and I've posted a fiddle too

Comment: yes i ran this code. it remove duplication but the resultant array is not with time sort. it gives
www.pqr.com with ...1154 but i need www.pqr.com with ...1170 time

Comment: Ohh my bad I didn't got that one. Yep you're right @splash58

Comment: yes can you help me with that. @Uchiha thanks for the above.

Comment: @Uchiha, why I did not sent my answer )))

Comment: @splash58 Didn't get you. And I've Solved that too

Comment: There's no need to assign the individual keys after `$result[$hash] = $value`. Other than that, this seems to be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks @deceze I've updated

Comment: Thanks @deceze that's the first one that I've posted an answer without using `isset`.  Seems need a Cup of Coffee